# CSS Float: Floating an image to the left of the text

Tags: html, css, css-float

For each post box, I want the thumbnail to float to the left and the text to float to the right. I do not want the thumb to wrap around the text.

Here is my html code:

```
<div class="post-container">                
   <div class="post-thumb"><img src="thumb.jpg" /></div>
   <div class="post-title">Post title</div>
   <div class="post-content"><p>post description description description etc etc etc</p></div>
</div>
```

I've tried a few ways and still can't get it to work... the text won't show on the right...

Here's my CSS code:

```
.post-container{
    margin: 20px 20px 0 0;  
    border:5px solid #333;
}

.post-thumb img {
    float: left;
    clear:left;
}

.post-content {
    float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Is this what you're after?

- I changed your title into a `h3` (header) tag, because it's a more semantic choice than using a `div`.

[***Live Demo #1***](http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/RXrvZ/)
[***Live Demo #2***](http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/RXrvZ/1/) *(with header at top, not sure if you wanted that)*

**HTML:**

```
<div class="post-container">                
    <div class="post-thumb"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x200/f0f/fff" /></div>
    <div class="post-content">
        <h3 class="post-title">Post title</h3>
        <p>post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc post desc </p>
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.post-container {
    margin: 20px 20px 0 0;  
    border: 5px solid #333;
    overflow: auto
}
.post-thumb {
    float: left
}
.post-thumb img {
    display: block
}
.post-content {
    margin-left: 210px
}
.post-title {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 200%
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. If I want the content of .post-content to align to bottom half of the post-thumb image, how do i do that? I cannot give height to '.post-content'.

Comment: what if i don't know the width of the image but now, `margin-left: 210px` on `.post-content` is there..! Is there a way to fix it without using js?

Comment: @ZekeDran: http://jsfiddle.net/RXrvZ/2474/, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7189608/how-do-i-make-an-input-element-occupy-all-remaining-horizontal-space/7190310#7190310

Answer (score 4):

Just need to float both elements left:

```
.post-container{
    margin: 20px 20px 0 0;  
    border:5px solid #333;
}

.post-thumb img {
    float: left;
}

.post-content {
    float: left;
}
```

Edit: actually, you do not need the width, just float both left

Comment: Make sure to have a div with clear:both underneath the #div.post-content as well.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this sample: http://jsfiddle.net/Epgvc/1/

I just floated the title to the left and added a `clear:both` div to the bottom..

Answer (score 1):

```css
.post-container{
    margin: 20px 20px 0 0;  
    border:5px solid #333;
    width:600px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.post-thumb img {
    float: left;
    clear:left;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    border:1px solid red;
}

.post-title {
     float:left;   
    margin-left:10px;
}

.post-content {
    float:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="post-container">                
   <div class="post-thumb"><img src="thumb.jpg" /></div>
   <div class="post-title">Post title</div>
   <div class="post-content"><p>post description description description etc etc etc</p></div>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ppR9a/)

Answer (score 1):

I almost always just use overflow:hidden on my text-elements in those situations, it often works like a charm ;)

```
.post-container {
 margin: 20px 20px 0 0;
 border:5px solid #333;
}
.post-thumb img {
 float: left;
}
.post-content {
 overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the width of post-content and post-thumb so that you get a two-column layout.

Answer (score 0):

Solution using ***display: flex*** (with responsive behavior): http://jsfiddle.net/dkulahin/w3472kct

**HTML:**

```
<div class="content">
    <img src="myimage.jpg" alt="" />
    <div class="details">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.content{
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}
.content img {
    width: 150px;
}
.details {
    width: calc(100% - 150px);
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .content {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .details {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```