# Stop floating with the end of a tag

Tags: html, css, css-float

I want to create a text that floats left around an image. Next paragraphs should only float around the next image.

```
<div>
   <div style="float: right; padding: 0 0 1em 1em;">
      <img src="myImage1.png" .../>
   </div>
   <p>
       This text should float around the...
   </p>
   <p>
       ... above myImage1.png.
   </p>
</div>

<div style="clear: both;">
   <div style="float: right; padding: 0 0 1em 1em;">
      <img src="myImage2.png" .../>
   </div>
   <p>
       This text should float around the...
   </p>
   <p>
       ... above myImage2.png.
   </p>
</div>
```

I want to avoid having to add `style="clear: both;"` on the **next** div, but want the floating image automatically stop floating at the end of the first top-level `</div>`, so each div can have the same style class:

```
<div class="floatBlock">
   ...
</div>

<div class="floatBlock">
   ...
</div>
```

which especially becomes useful if there are -tags inside (the first floatBlock's image should not float below the h3):

```
<div class="floatBlock">
   ...
</div>

<h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>

<div class="floatBlock">
   ...
</div>
```

I hope to have described my goal understandable.

How to define the style for `floatBlock` so the nested images do not float outside?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS Float: Floating an image to the left of the text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198392/css-float-floating-an-image-to-the-left-of-the-text)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to add the `clear` with the `after` selector. You can add this in your CSS file:

```
.floatBlock:after {
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
}
```

This is of course I guess. I have no proper way to test it without your CSS.

Answer (score 4):

There is no reason why you can't just have `clear:both` applied to **all** of the elements. So you could do it in your class like this:

```
.floatBlock{
    clear:both;
}
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/9yyuy00n/)

---

If you need to cope with short test and big images, and also have other elements in between the `floatBlock` elements (as per comments), then it would make sense to put a clear element after each one. Like so:

```
<div class="floatBlock">
    ...
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>

.clear {
    clear:both;
}
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/9yyuy00n/9/)

Comment: @ThomasS.: Why don't you just try it? But the answer is [yes](http://jsfiddle.net/9yyuy00n/1/)

Comment: This does not prevent the image from floating below the <h3>.

Comment: @ThomasS.: What do you mean? Show me a working example that is what you want differently from what I gave you

Comment: Take your example, reduce the text of your first two paragraphs to a very short one, increase the first image's height, e.g. to 350x450, and add a <h3>hello</h3> before the second <div class="floatBlock">. "hello" will be shown left beside the first image.